# How to connect 2 switches of different networks in Mininet?

Tags: mininet

I am trying to solve an assignment where i have 2 different networks in 2 different VMs.

```
VM1:
H1----->S1------>C1
 and on VM2:
H2------>S2------>C2
```

I know that with GRE tunneling i can connect 2 different networks but in that case i remotely connect S1 to C2 and S2 to C1.
But here I dont want that controller of VM1 to controll the Switch of VM2.

I was thinking that if it is possible that i can somehow make a connection between S1 and S2 through GRE tunneling.
So when i want H1 to ping H2 it should go like from H1 to S1 and from S1 to S2 and then to H2.

Anyone please?

Comment: Did the below answer helped ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is overall of what I think you need to do.

You have two VMs, let's call them A and B. On both of them you need to have a tap interface, and some mininet topo running. You mininet topo should be connected to tap interface. Then you need to connect taps together (tunneling); so this would connect the two mininet topos as well.

I guess the tricky part is how to connect the mininet to tap interfaces. Have a look at how I do it in [python code](https://github.com/Ehsan70/Mininet_LINC_script/blob/master/SimpleOptTopoScratch.py).  Essential this section of the code does that job:

```
    # This would connect switch s1 tap interface named tap1 
    self.addIntf(s1,'tap0')
```

Also when you add a controller I think since each VM has its own local host , using same localhost ip and same port number is fine. But i'm not sure, so in case, change the port number for one of them.

```
    # So this is ip address and port number of controller. 
    # both mininet codes should have this line, although with different port number
    c = RemoteController('c','0.0.0.0',6633)
```

The details:

1. Create a tap interface in both VMs and start them up.
2. Connect them (tunneling).
3. Run `sudo mn -c` on both VMs to clean the mininet environment.
4. Run the controller on both VMs. Make sure the ports are different.
5. Run your mininet topo on each of them.

Note that the name you use to create the Tap interface should same as the one you use in the your code for mininet topo.

Hope it helps. Let me know if i wasn't clear on something.

Comment: Hi Ehsan!Thanks for the reply and answering in such detail.                             
 
it may look like dumb, but i have no idea how to create tap interface in mininet?             Can you please give me any idea or some kinds of codes or anything that help me understanding on how to create Tap interface?

Comment: No problem. Here is a link to a [bash script](https://github.com/Ehsan70/RyuOEApps/blob/master/TapSetup.bash) which creates a given number of  Tap interfaces and  brings them up. In that code I use the following two command: 1. `sudo tunctl -t <tapname>` for example: `sudo tunctl -t tap1`   . 2. And then to bring the up you use `sudo ip link set dev <tapname> up` for example `sudo ip link set dev tap1 up`

Comment: Hi thanks for the codes, but when i run the bash file in mininet console it says "sudo: tunctl:command not found." . i tried installing uml-utilities but it shows an error like "some index files failed to download...." when i run this command sudo apt-get install uml-utilities it says "unable to fetch some archives..."  i have searched alot but i cant update resolv.conf files. any idea to get out of this situation? BTW thanx again.

Comment: Are u running the commands in mininet console? they should be executed in os terminal not mininet console.

Comment: Hi Ehsan! in order to run bash files in os terminal, do i need to install "cygwin" or is there another way to run it?

Comment: If you are using Windows you need `cygwin` in order to run linux commands (I'm not sure how you can do that tho). 

I really recommand using a linux based VM image . There is a All-in-one VM configure by SDN hub which has all the necessities in this field. Instructions are [here](http://sdnhub.org/tutorials/sdn-tutorial-vm/).

Comment: Ehsan, i am stuck here. you said that "Create a tap interface in both VMs and start them up" and for this you gave me a bash script and asked me to run it in OS terminal. i am not sure that if i run the script in OS, how am i gona create and start them up in VM(like in mininet). i hope i am not bothering you too much.

Comment: So you create a tap interface in your OS. One end of the Tap interface is connected to the mininet switch and other end would be connected to the Tap interface which was created in the other VM. Not sure if that was your question

Comment: i installed cygwin and placed the bash script (which you gave ) in cygwin/bin/ . when i execute the script it was showing these errors                                      "/usr/bin/abc.bash: line 2: $'\r': command not found
/usr/bin/abc.bash: line 31: syntax error near unexpected token `$'\r''
'usr/bin/abc.bash: line 31: ` for count in $(seq 1 $1);" now as i have fixed these. it shows "/usr/bin/abc.bash: line 41: sudo: command not found" how to fix this one

Comment: @zafarmalik I'll be honest with you I'm not familiar with cygwin. I recommend put a another post specifically on this topic.